# Which database of which instance is used by SQL Server for initialization?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, memory-management, terminology

- "Also, master is the database that records the existence of all other databases and the location of those database files and records the initialization information for SQL Server. Therefore, SQL Server cannot start if the master database is unavailable. In SQL Server, system objects are no longer stored in the master database; instead, they are stored in the Resource database" [1]

So, without which database - MASTER or RESOURCE - SQL Server cannot start and from which of the possibly multiple instances of SQL Server?

[1]
master Database (SQL Server 2008 R2 Books Online)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each instance has it's own master, model and resource database. The instance cannot start if *any* of these is unavailable.